# How can I include a case insentive string literal in my Regex pattern?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a list of function calls in a Domain-Specific Language that I need to replace.

So say I have the following strings that I want to match.

```
$Open($#ScreenName:"System A Overview")
$Open($#ScreenName: "System A Overview")
$Open($#ScreenName:   "System A Overview")
$Open(   $#ScreenName:"System A Overview")
$Open(   $#ScreenName:"system a Overview")   // Fails to match
$Open("System A Overview")
$Open("system A overview") // Fails to match
```

The following does just fine when the part in the quote has the same case.

```
\$Open(\s*)\(([^\"]*)((?-i)\"System\ A\ Overview)\"
```

But I need to match the string literal `System A Overview`case insensitively

Here is my line in C# generating the pattern

```
var OpenPattern = $@"{Regex.Escape("$Open")}(\s*)\(([^\""]*)\""{Regex.Escape(screenName.Old)}\""";
```

`screenName.Old` could be anything, I have a whole list that I need to search through.

How can I do this?

Edit: I do not want to match everything case insenstivly just part of it, if this is possible anyway.

For example, if it starts with `$open` or `$oPen` it should not match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use RegexOptions.IgnoreCase in Regex.Match/Regex.Matches/Regex.IsMatch function. Or you can use (?i) pattern.
Here are brief samples:

**Sample 1:**

```
List<string> testString = new List<string>
{
    "hello World",
    "Hello World",
    "hEllo wOrld"
};
string pattern = "(?i)Hello World"; //It means after (?i) pattern will be processed as case insensitive
foreach(string str in testString)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern)) //No RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
        Console.WriteLine($"[Matched]: {str}");
}
//Result:
//[Matched]: hello World
//[Matched]: Hello World
//[Matched]: hEllo wOrld
```

**Sample 2:**

```
List<string> testString = new List<string>
{
    "hello World",
    "Hello World",
    "hEllo wOrld"
};
string pattern = "Hello World";
foreach(string str in testString)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        Console.WriteLine($"[Matched]: {str}");
}
//Result:
//[Matched]: hello World
//[Matched]: Hello World
//[Matched]: hEllo wOrld
```

Comment: Sorry I edited my Question with additional clarification (see bottom of it), I only want part of it to match case-insensitively

Comment: That got my in the right direction I ended up putting it inside a group like this
`((?i){Regex.Escape(screenName.Old)}) `

Comment: \$Open(\s*)\(([^\"]*)((?-i)\"((?i)System\ A\ Overview))\"

https://regex101.com/r/B9Xkyr/1

Comment: you can use that pattern. is that what you want? 
check here
https://regex101.com/r/B9Xkyr/1

Comment: Yes, haha I was using the same tool to test https://regex101.com/r/1dW3Mb/1, Thank you